# Columns being duplicated IdentityUserRole C# IdentityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

well, my table IdentityUserRole has two more unwanted columns which are both AppUser_Id and IdentityRole_Id.

I'm having troubles while trying to register an user within a role.
I found out that if I copy the content from UserId into AppUser_Id the app works perfect.

Through Fluent API, this is where I define the keys:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>()
                    .HasKey(iur => iur.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()
                    .HasKey(iul => iul.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CourseModel>()
                    .HasKey(c => c.CourseID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<FeedbackModel>()
                    .HasKey(f => f.FeedBackId);
```

I had to do so, because the NuGet Console was rising some errors because IdentityUserRole didn't have a key defined, so I did that.

I'm 100% sure that that's what is f***ing me up.

Right now, this is my table IdentityUserRole:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the definition of the IdentityUserRole class?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `IdentityUserRole` class looks something like:

```
class IdentityUserRole
{
   ...
   public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
   public IdentityRole IdentityRole { get; set; }
}
```

Entity framework is generating the AppUser_Id and IdentityRole_Id foreign columns automatically, as you haven't specified foreign keys for the `AppUser` and `IdentityRole` properties.

If you want to use the `UserId` and `RoleId` columns for this, you'll need to either add an annotation to the properties in `IdentityUserRole`, e.g.

```
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
```

or define the relationship using the fluent API in your context.

You should also define a primary key for the `IdentityUserRole` type (e.g. `IdentityUserRoleId`).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by simply adding '***base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);***' at the end of the override function '***OnModelCreating***'.